# DHCP log only visible from some programs

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, logging, dhcp-server

We recently changed the DHCP service at my workplace from a RHEL server to a Windows 2008 R2 server. As I'm used to monitoring the logfiles with "tail -f" I thought I'd try to read the logs on the new server with baretail.exe.

The problem is, when I try to open the C:\Windows\System32\dhcp folder I get an error message that reads:

```
Windows can't find 'C:\Windows\System32\dhcp'. Check the spelling and try again.
```

I can see the folder just fine through Explorer and I can open the logfiles themselves with Notepad, but the folder and it's contents doesn't seem to exist for baretail.

Does anybody have any idea why this could be?

Alternatively; does anybody have any suggestions of how best to view logfiles on a Windows server.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely baretail.exe is a 32-bit program, and sees the SYSWOW64 directory instead of SYSTEM32 (in 64-bit Windows the SYSTEM32 directory really contains 64-bit DLLs, and the SYSWOW64 directory contains 32-bit DLLs). According to [Wikipedia article on WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64), 32-bit applications can access the real SYSTEM32 directory as `%SystemRoot%\sysnative`. Another option is to change log location in the DHCP server configuration, so that log files are outside SYSTEM32.

Comment: That was it. I tried to open the file through %SystemRoot%\sysnative and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[Baretail.exe](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/index.php) works for me.